# Label not updating swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am new to iOS. I am retrieving the data from the accelerometer using MotionKit. I can see on the terminal that the values from the accelerometer are being retrieved every 0.1 sec, unfortunately the label updates only one time. Why is the label not updating?

```
@IBOutlet weak var xLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var zLabel: UILabel!

var xAccel = 0.0
var yAccel = 0.0
var zAccel = 0.0


private let queue = NSOperationQueue()
let motionKit = MotionKit()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    motionKit.getAccelerometerValues(interval: 0.1){
        (x, y, z) in

        println("x: \(x)")
        println("y:  \(y)")
        println("z: \(z)")
        println();


        self.xAccel = x
        self.yAccel = y
        self.zAccel = z





        self.xLabel.text = "\(self.xAccel)"

        self.yLabel.text = "\(self.yAccel)"

        self.zLabel.text = "\(self.zAccel)"








    }
```

Comment: Try updating the UI on the main thread.

Comment: To build upon what Thomas said try using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {YOUR CODE})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this MotionKit Framework executes as block you have to update the UILabels in the Main Queue, something like this will solve this problem but still really mess

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var xLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var zLabel: UILabel!

    var xAccel = 0.0
    var yAccel = 0.0
    var zAccel = 0.0


    private let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    let motionKit = MotionKit()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        motionKit.getAccelerometerValues(interval: 0.1){
            (x, y, z) in

            println("x: \(x)")
            println("y:  \(y)")
            println("z: \(z)")
            println();


            self.xAccel = x
            self.yAccel = y
            self.zAccel = z

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.xLabel.text = "\(self.xAccel)"
                self.yLabel.text = "\(self.yAccel)"
                self.zLabel.text = "\(self.zAccel)"

            });

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Hopethis helps

Comment: Do you have to worry about strong references to `self` inside a closure? I don’t know Swift, but I do know Objective-C, and this case is familiar: since your object owns `motionKit`, and `motionKit` owns the closure passed in `getAccelerometerValues()`, and the closure references `self`, you probably need to [weakify `self`](http://blog.xebia.com/2014/12/19/swift-self-reference-in-inner-closure/).